# Numpy aggregated mean

Tags: python, numpy

I want to calculate the mean over a numpy array but within a window from the beginning of the array until the actual value of the array. Here´s an example:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...]
windowed_means = [1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, ...]
```

The calculus are like:

```
windowed_means = [1/1, (1+2)/2, (1+2+3)/3, (1+2+3+4)/4 , ...]
```

Is there any function for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
windowed_means = np.cumsum(array)/np.arange(1,len(array)+1)
```

`numpy.cumsum` is the [cumulative sum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html).